# Spring rest controller @RequestParam validation

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to validate the request param.I have gone through number of blogs and answer and did the same.
Added @Validated on the controller class.

**Method in controller:**

```
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getHistory(
@Valid @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{0,1}$", message = "Invalid 
emp") @NotNull(message = "input cannot be null") @RequestParam(name = "emp") 
String emp) { method body..........}
```

**Controller Advice**

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleValidationFailure(ConstraintViolationException ex) {

  StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();

  for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
      messages.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
  }

  return messages.toString();
}
```

**Config:**

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
  return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

After doing all this now I am getting a 404 error.
"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available"

Comment: I am using a spring boot

Comment: You getting any more detailed errors in your logs?

Comment: No exception in logs

Comment: did you have it in a working state before?

Comment: yes it is working fine after removing @validation from the controller.
But the request param is not getting validated

Comment: Note: Using `@Valid`, `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown when validation fails. However, with `@Validated`, `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing [@ResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) annotation over a method in controller advice. It causes an error, because Spring is trying to locate template with name returned as a `String` from this method, so during REST call you get something like this:

```
{
    "error": "Not Found", 
    "exception": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException", 
    "message": "No message available", 
    "path": "/history", 
    "status": 404, 
    "timestamp": 1502293311543
}
```

Adding `@ResponseBody` annotation to `handleValidationFailure(ConstraintViolationException ex)` method means that when you return a String it's not a template name but the response object itself.

Alternatively you can use `ResponseEntity<String>` as a return type in your advice method, e.g.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleValidationFailure(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();

    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
        messages.append(violation.getMessage());
    }

    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(messages.toString());
}
```

so you don't have to annotate method with `@ResponseBody` and Spring will now that your response is not a view name but response body itself. I hope it helps.

#### UPDATE

I assume you are calling incorrect endpoint. I have created a small Spring Boot application that replicates your problem using provided information:

> https://github.com/wololock/rest-validation-demo

Feel free to clone it and run it. After running you can try calling `/history` endpoint with:

```
curl "localhost:8080/history?emp=AZ000001A"
```

and it will display in return:

```
{"id":"AZ000001A","name":"Joe Doe"}%
```

If you call this endpoint with `emp` that violates validation rules:

```
curl "localhost:8080/history?emp=sd"
```

you will get following response:

```
{"message":"Your request contains errors","errors":[{"getHistory.arg0":"Invalid emp"}]}
```

My assumption is that in your case you are calling your endpoint incorrectly. There is popular misunderstanding in using `@RestController` annotation. I saw people using it like `@RestController("/someRootPath")` and then they expected to have endpoints like

```
localhost:8080/someRootPath/...
```

which is not correct. Value passed to `@RestController` annotation is nothing else than:

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

You can always check console log to see what are the final mappings for your controllers, e.g.

```
2017-08-09 20:40:45.663  INFO 1340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6385cb26: startup date [Wed Aug 09 20:40:44 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-09 20:40:45.696  INFO 1340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/history],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.github.wololock.restvalidationdemo.Employee> com.github.wololock.restvalidationdemo.EmployeeController.getHistory(java.lang.String)
2017-08-09 20:40:45.698  INFO 1340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-08-09 20:40:45.698  INFO 1340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-08-09 20:40:45.708  INFO 1340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/employee] onto handler '/employee'
2017-08-09 20:40:45.714  INFO 1340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-09 20:40:45.714  INFO 1340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I did the same but no luck :( same

{"timestamp":1502294676236,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"*****"}

Comment: I am getting this with even valid data

Comment: @ChandreshMishra Please take a look at updated answer. I have prepared a small Spring Boot app that replicates your validation problem. It should help you solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your code. It helped me a lot. I appreciate your effort. I found the problem in my code and replicated the same in your code base as well.
My controller class is implementing the interface having the contract. 
If you add the  implements EmployeeContract

public interface EmployeeContract {

 public ResponseEntity<Employee> getHistory( String emp);
}
You will get the 404 error.

Comment: Szymon Stepniak - could you please help

Comment: @ChandreshMishra I will check it later today and will get back to you.

Comment: Szymon Stepniak  -Thanks

Comment: @ChandreshMishra I've updated the code with the interface you have mentioned earlier and it does not work as you described. `@Validated` annotation + implementing interface seems to be broken in Spring. After adding this interface and keeping `@Validated` annotation it makes `/history` endpoint not mapped to the application, which is quite weird. I have never used interfaces for controllers tbh and would suggest you to do the same. Defining an interface makes more sense e.g. for services that you can inject with `@Autowired` to your controller. I'll post an update if I find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Szymon Stepniak. Adding a interface is a business need. So unfortunately can't remove it.