# Spring 5 PathVariable Validation Causing Http 404

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

When I add `@Validated` to a Spring `RestConstroller` I am receiving a HTTP 404 response for that Controllers endpoints. Before adding the annotation the endpoint is found without any issues.

The issue is with `@PathVariable` specifically and I have validation working correctly (using `@Valid`) with non-primitive RequestBody parameters.

There are quite a few articles on this and I've spent a significant amount of time trying several variations without success. The most simple is .

According to this simple example https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/05/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/ I believe it should be as simple as adding `@Validated` to the Controller, leaving off `@Valid` for the PathVariable parameter and adding a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean. Preferably I would use `@Valid` instead of `@Validated`.

I am using Spring 5 (not boot) and have hibernate-validator 6.0.16.Final on the classpath

**Problematic RestController**

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "practices")
public class RestPracticeResource implements PracticeResource {

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Practice> getPractice(@Id @PathVariable("id") final String id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        final UUID uuidId = UUID.fromString(id);
    }
}
```

**Working RestController for RequestBody**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "accounts")
public class RestAccountResource implements AccountResource {

    @Override
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDto> create(@NotNull @Valid @RequestBody final CreateAccountDto createAccountDto)
            throws ResourceAlreadyExistsException {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Id Annotation**

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = Id.IdValidator.class)
public @interface Id {

    // ... Stock standard code here

    class IdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Id, String> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(final Id id) {}

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(final String id, final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            // Basic REGEX match for UUID format
            return ValidationUtil.isValidId(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**ExceptionHander**

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleConstraintViolationException(final ConstraintViolationException ex,
                                                                         final WebRequest webRequest) {
    // .. extract violations into standard format
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

**MethodValidationPostProcessor bean**

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

**Actual Results**

As soon as I add `@Validated` I receive Http 404 responses for the `/practices/{id}` endpoint not matter what format id I provider. If I remove `@Validated` I can pass a valid UUID and all is ok or pass an invalid UUID and get an Exception thrown from `UUID.fromString(id)`.

`@Id` is ignored if I attempt to use `@Valid` as per the request body validation.

**Expected Results**

Adding `@Validated` will enabled the `@Id` annotation validation and a `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown when a non-UUID formatted `{id}` is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old question that is similar to this and i found the solution i was looking for. Link: [Spring rest controller @RequestParam validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594623/spring-rest-controller-requestparam-validation?rq=1)

To summarize  Szymon Stepniak's answer. This is a spring-mvc bug. I'm using hibernate version 5.2.4.Final and spring-webmvc 4.3.8.RELEASE version.

If the rest controller implements an interface and we also add the @Validated annotation the RequestMappingHandlerMapping will not register the endpoint. I am not aware of the root cause. But removing the "implement interface" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Proxy Target Class and it will work with
`@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

Answer (score 0):

I added the usual stuff you have done (libraries in pom, @Valid on RequestBody etc)  and got a 404 too!

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

What the Spring docs (and many blogs) leave it as subtle is that Spring looks for an exit point to throw the error but if that exit doesn't exist, it will reply with 404. After reading a lot especially this [blog](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/), adding this class got Spring to recognize @Valid and find an exit point to throw the error

```
    @RestControllerAdvice
    @Order(1) 
    public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "error/404" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleUnexpectedException(Exception e) {
        return "views/base/rest-error";         
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public String handlemethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) { //
        // TODO you can choose to return your custom object here, which will then get transformed to json/xml etc.
        return "Sorry, that was not quite right: " + exception.getMessage();
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public String handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException exception) { //
        // TODO you can choose to return your custom object here, which will then get transformed to json/xml etc.
        return "Sorry, that was not quite right: " + exception.getMessage();
    }

    
}
```